# Multiple 'path' parameters in flask route lead to incorrect parsing

Tags: python, flask, url, path, routes

#### Problem Description

When using the flask `@app.route`, it should be possible to send three *path* parameters right after the other, but the parsing on the flask side picks them apart incorrectly when there are '/' involved.

#### Minimal Example

The Flask Server uses this routing, where there are three 'path' parameters *first*, *second* and *third*:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

@app.route('/pathtest/<path:first>/<path:second>/<path:third>/', methods=['GET'])
def pathTest(first, second, third):
    print("1: " + first, flush=True) 
    print("2: " + second, flush=True)
    print("3: " + third, flush=True) 
    return jsonify({ 'data': '%s' % True})
```

If we want to send three parameters, which are encoded as follows:

| String | Encoded |
| --- | --- |
| 'hello?/this' | hello%3F%2Fthis |
| 'is/a' | is%2Fa |
| 'test!' | test%21 |

the entire url which we call (with our server on port 8085) is

`http://0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello%3F%2Fthis/is%2Fa/test%21/`.

#### Result:

**Expected**

```
1: 'hello?/this'
2: 'is/a'
3: 'test!'
```

**Actual**

```
1: 'hello?'
2: 'this'
3: 'is/a/test!'
```

#### 'Solution'

what does seem to work is splitting up the route:

```
@app.route('/pathtest/first/<path:first>/second/<path:second>/third/<path:third>/', methods=['GET'])
```

I use the flask build in server for testing but have also tried it through nginx.

#### Question

What is the explanation for this behavior? Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing in the *path* documentation or the way I encode my strings on the client side?

best wishes

### Answers

0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello%3F%2Fthis/is%2Fa/test%21 will be converted to 0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello?/this/is/a/test! before Flask receives it.

This does not seem to be the case; checking `request.url` for both inbuild flask server and with nginx and uWSGI in between both show that the 'expected' encoded url `0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello%3F%2Fthis/is%2Fa/test%21`.

Comment: when I use `urllib.parse.unquote('http://0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello%3F%2Fthis/is%2Fa/test%21/')` then I get `'http://0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello?/this/is/a/test!/'` and I don't know where is end of first path, and where is end of second path - and probably Flask has the same problem. First it may unquote it and later it has problem to detect ends of paths. You should use char which you will not have in paths - ie. `|`, `,`,`;`,etc.

Comment: How are you running your Flask application? Do you use built-in server or use some other (for example `nginx`)?

Comment: if you use `from flask import request` and in function you use `print(request.url)` then you see `http://0.0.0.0:5000/pathtest/hello%3F/this/is/a/test%21/` and this is url which it tries to split on three paths - and there is no method to recognize where is end of first and second path.

Comment: It seems to be a limitation in WSGI or Apache that convert %2F to / before Flask handles it. See https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/900 for more info and some workarounds

Comment: @furas from what I understood from here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/ when asking for 'path' it should *'also accept slashes [in the string]'*

Comment: @Sefan that's true, but as noted in the issue , *"using the path type annotation, would solve this."* which is the strategy I think I used, unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: `path1/path2` creates also correct `path` and you can't recognize where is end of `path1` - you main problem is that you use `/` between `path1` and `path2` and this create single path. Annotation can works if you use single `path` but you have many paths and this makes problem. ie. if you have `hello/world/of/python` then you can't say if it is `hello` and `world/of/python` or `hello/world` and `of/python` or `hello/world/of` and `python`

Comment: @r.m. http://0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello%3F%2Fthis/is%2Fa/test%21/ will be converted to http://0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello?/this/is/a/test!/ before Flask receives it.

Comment: thank you! Your `solution` part saved me after 3 hours of frustration!

Answer (score 0):

*What is the explanation for this behavior?*

It seems that URL-decoding comes first, then path parsing, so

```
http://0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello%3F%2Fthis/is%2Fa/test%21/
```

becomes

```
http://0.0.0.0:8085/pathtest/hello?/this/is/a/test!/
```

which then is path parsed and as `%`-decoding was done earlier there is no way to tell apart `/` and `%2F`. I suspect this might depend on used server and its' setting. As relying on difference `/` and `%2F` is clearly not robust I suggest changing your specification so other character (which will never appear inside path) is used for shearing paths.

Comment: I don't understand why this path `@app.route('/pathtest/first/<path:first>/second/<path:second>/third/<path:third>/', methods=['GET'])``` works everywhere though. I can see that relying on `%2F` isn't very robust - but converting `/` to `|` or similar seems like an accident waiting to happen. Note, that I want to send 'generic' strings, not just explicit paths.